# Editing part sizes of a 3d model

Tags: three.js

I want to develop a web app to entering measurements of a man and displaying a 3d model with these measurements. I have chosen three.js to start it. And I downloaded a 3d model named `standard-male-figure` from clara.io. Here is my code to display human model.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import * as THREE from "three-full";

const styles = (/*theme*/) => ({

});

class ThreeDView extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);


        this.start = this.start.bind(this);
        this.stop = this.stop.bind(this);
        this.renderScene - this.renderScene.bind(this);
        this.animate = this.animate.bind(this);

    }

    componentDidMount() {


        const width = this.mount.clientWidth;
        const height = this.mount.clientHeight;

        //ADD SCENE
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

        //ADD CAMERA
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100,1);
        this.camera.position.z = 12;
        this.camera.position.y = 0;
        this.camera.position.x = 0;

        //ADD RENDERER
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        this.renderer.setClearColor("#f0f0f0");
        this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
        this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

        // MOUSE ROTATION
        this.orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera,this.renderer.domElement);
        this.orbit.update();

        //ADD LIGHTS
        this.light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff,1.3);
        this.light.position.z = 10;
        this.light.position.y=20;
        this.scene.add(this.light);

        // ADD MAN FIGURE
        const loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        loader.load("/models/standard-male-figure.dae",(manFigure)=>{
            this.man = manFigure;
            this.man.name = "man-figure";
            this.man.scene.position.y = -10;
            this.scene.add(this.man.scene);
        },undefined,()=>alert("Loading failed"));


        this.start();
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.stop();
        this.mount.removeChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    }

    start() {
        if (!this.frameId) {
            this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
        }
    }

    stop () {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId);
    }

    animate () {

        this.renderScene();
        this.frameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    }

    renderScene () {
        this.orbit.update();
        this.light.position.z = this.camera.position.z;
        this.light.position.y=this.camera.position.y+20;
        this.light.position.x=this.camera.position.x;
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }


    render() {


        return (
            <div style={{ height: "640px" }} ref={(mount) => { this.mount = mount; }} >

            </div>
        );
    }
}

ThreeDView.propTypes = {
    values: PropTypes.object
};

/*
all values in inches
values = {
 heightOfHand:10,
 , etc..
}
*/

export default withStyles(styles)(ThreeDView);
```

values is measurements that user is entering. I have no idea about how to start updating 3d model with these measurements. Please give me a starting point  or any advise to complete this. Thank You!.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can get the current size and scale of your man

```
const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.man)
const currentObjectSize = box.getSize()
const currentObjectScale = this.man.scale
```

and when an user update the size value (newSize), you can calculate a new scale for you man

```
const newScale = new THREE.Vector3(
    currentObjectScale.x * newSize.x/currentObjectSize.x,
    currentObjectScale.y * newSize.y/currentObjectSize.y,
    currentObjectScale.z * newSize.z/currentObjectSize.z
)
```

and update your man with  this scale

```
this.man.scale.set(newScale.x, newScale.y, newScale.z)
```

Comment: But I don't want to scale the whole man. I want to scale only a part of him. (Ex:- Round of his neck). Your codes to scale the whole man size.